# The import java.security.MessageDigest cannot be resolved

Tags: java

When I tried to import MessageDigest class, Eclipse told me this error. But isn't this class included in JDK? How can I solve this problem?

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Md5Util {
    public String EncoderByMd5(String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        java.security.MessageDigest md5 = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        BASE64Encoder base64en = new BASE64Encoder();
        String newstr=base64en.encode(md5.digest(str.getBytes("utf-8")));
        return newstr;
      }
}
```

Comment: Which JDK are you using ?

Comment: @AnishB. I'm using JDK-12.0.1

Comment: Is it only `java.security.MessageDigest` that has this problem? Are you sure you've configured Eclipse to use the JDK you've downloaded?

Comment: JDK 12 is [modular](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html). How have you configured your Eclipse project? Have you created a `module-info.java` file? How have you configured the java build path for your Eclipse project?

Comment: I have solved this problem by adding `requires java.base;` in the `module-info.java` file. Thank you so much. @AnishB.  @Abra @Slaw

Comment: I wonder why that fixes your problem. The `java.base` module is implicitly required by all modules; you shouldn't have to manually add `requires java.base;`.

Comment: I have the same problem in Eclipse using Zulu18.32+13-CA. The maven build works, so it seams to be an Eclipse bug.